# react router. get all path parameters with `match.params `

Tags: reactjs, react-router, routeparams

in my `React` application, I have a route to another component like

`<Route path={'/:pId/external/:folder'} exact={true} component={Externals} />`

now in the `Externals` component, I want to get the `:pId` value.

using `this.props.match.params` just gives me the last param which is `:folder` and I can not get the value of `:pId`. How should I do that?

Answer (score 0):

`props.match.params` contains all of the parameters. Here's an example showing how to get at them:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Route, BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";

const Externals = props => {
  return (
    <div>
      pId = {props.match.params.pId}
      <br />
      folder = {props.match.params.folder}
    </div>
  );
};
function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Route
        path={"/:pId/external/:folder"}
        exact={true}
        component={Externals}
      />
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Here's a code sandbox showing this:

URL to edit: https://codesandbox.io/s/nwlrm3n66p

URL to view sample output: https://nwlrm3n66p.codesandbox.io/mypid/external/myfolder

Comment: Thanks, but for some reason I do not have access to `:pId`. 
I have wrapped the `Rout` with `Router`
`<Provider><Router><React.Fragment><Route>....`

Comment: Please show the code of how you’re trying to access `:pId`.

Comment: it is written in the question: `this.props.match.params.***` in the *** I just get `folder` sugesstion and typing `params.pId` results error

Comment: Please show in your question the actual line of code that you tried and the error that resulted. Even more helpful would be to fork my code sandbox and modify that to show the simplest version of your code that reproduces your error. Then include the link to that sandbox in your question.